# what chip does thetileapp BTLE tracker uses

Tags: bluetooth, system-on-chip

I am working on some BTLE prototypes,
I saw this tracker http://www.thetileapp.com/

what chip would this "tile" be using?

im going to be playing with the TI SoC CC2540 http://www.ti.com/product/cc2540&DCMP=LowPowerRFICs+Other&HQS=Other+OT+cc2540

but still to big to use as a tile.

What other option would  this gadget use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the [Nordic nRF8001](http://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/Bluetooth-R-low-energy/nRF8001): 5 x 5mm QFN package.

Comment: That part likely requires an external microcontroller unless there's some minimal automatic functionality.  Perhaps it's being confused with the nRF8002 which contains an ARM core?  The coin cell is likely the size determining factor, not the chip.

Comment: That sounds good too. This question is pretty open, not sure why this was selected as an answer, but I'll take it.